# geomnearest don't calc on QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have an attribute that is calculated with the function "geomnearest('sampling', 'fid')" in a tree table. It is ok on QGIS on PC but don't work on QFIELD ?
[image: conception form]

Comment: `geomnearest` is [not yet](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/145) a core function of QGIS. It is part of refFunctions plugin.

Comment: and just the core function are ok ?

Comment: I am not very familiar with QField yet, but don't know about a possibility of installing plugins. But you need this plugin for this function.